# How to Generate File of a determinate Size in Windows?

Tags: windows, scripting, file, filesystems

How is the Best and fastest way to do it?

Comment: What language/environment in Windows? cmd-files? Powershell? C#?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I found this [Page](http://thebackroomtech.com/2009/01/16/howto-generate-many-files-of-a-particular-size-in-windows/), I try it and work great.

To create a single File use

```
fsutil file createnew filename filesize
```

To create a lot of Files use

```
For /L %i in (1,1,25000) do fsutil file createnew A%i.tmp 12288
```

will create 25,000 files of 12288 bytes (12KB) named A1.tmp, A2.tmp, A3,tmp…

Comment: Beware that this only generates so called sparse file - you get a record in a folder with a file size but not actual data clusters assigned with the file. So for purposes like testing, zeroing or blocking off large blocks of data clusters it's useless.

Comment: @ZXX: I don't think that `fsutile file createnew <file> <size>` creates _sparse_ files - the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/fsutil-file) make no mention of that, and running `fsutil sparse queryflag <file>` on a file created this way indeed suggests that the file is _not_ sparse.

Answer (score 46):

PowerShell:

```ps
$f = new-object System.IO.FileStream c:\temp\test.dat, Create, ReadWrite
$f.SetLength(42MB)
$f.Close()
```

This will create a file `c:\temp\test.dat` that consists of 42MB of nullbytes. You can of course just give byte count instead as well. (42MB = 42 * 1048576 for PowerShell).

**Note:**
Keep in mind that unless you specify the full path (in my example, `C:\temp\test.dat`), using relative
paths (i.e `.\test.dat`) will only create files on the directory where PS was started in, i.e. `["C:\users\currentUser"]` if you start PS from the `Run...` command, or `["C:\Windows\system32"]` if you start it with `Shift+RightClick (OR) Alt->F>S>R` on the windows explorer.
To workaround this, you must change the underlying directory (you can check it with this as a command on PS:
`[IO.directory]::GetCurrentDirectory()`) to the current path you're on in the PS console, simply including the line:

```ps
[IO.directory]::SetCurrentDirectory($(get-location).Path)
```

So, to wrap it up, you make it work with the relative path you're currently in:

```ps
[IO.directory]::setCurrentDirectory($(get-location).Path) #Changes directory to current PS directory
[Int64]$size = 150MB #This allows you to set the size beforehand
$f = new-object System.IO.FileStream .\test.dat, Create, ReadWrite
$f.SetLength($size)
$f.Close()
```

Comment: I  might add that this is extremely fast to do.

Comment: @msanford In fact, you can use relative paths, but they will be relative to the directory PowerShell was started in (i.e. `[IO.Directory]::GetCurrentDirectory()`), and not relative to the directory you switched to using the `cd` or  `Set-Location` command.

Comment: Which is generally true for any kind of COM or .NET interop you perform inside PowerShell.

Comment: @mihi Thank you for that additional details; I assumed it was something of this nature! So, for those getting New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "3" argument(s): "Could not find a part of the path c:\some\path\test.dat` see above :)

Comment: @Anders unbelievably fast

Answer (score 4):

```
c:\>fsutil file createnew /?
Usage : fsutil file createnew <filename> <length>
   Eg : fsutil file createnew C:\testfile.txt 1000
```