# How to create n amount of files of X size using powershell?

Tags: powershell, automation

So, I have a folder and I'd like to create say 10 files of 150MB to test something.
How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an extension of the answer given at:
[How to Generate File of a determinate Size in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808005/how-to-generate-file-of-a-determinate-size-in-windows/808249#808249)
All that would be missing is a [`for` loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_for?view=powershell-7.2) and a max amount of files.

```
[IO.directory]::setCurrentDirectory($(get-location).Path) #Changes directory to current PS directory
[Int64]$size = 150MB #This allows you to set the size beforehand
[Int16]$AmountOfFiles = 10
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $AmountOfFiles; $i++) {
    $f = new-object System.IO.FileStream ".\test_$i.dat", Create, ReadWrite
    $f.SetLength($Size)
    $f.Close()
}
```

And lets go one by one the lines, just for fun and clarity:

```
[IO.directory]::setCurrentDirectory($(get-location).Path) #Changes directory to current PS directory
```

As explained on the previous answer, PS session has an "underlying" path used by .Net that it's not the same as the "current directory" (`get-location` or `pwd`), therefore we have to "manually" change it. That's achieved with the `$(Get-Location).Path` portion of the code, it will set the "underlying" path to the same path as the PSSession.

```
[Int64]$size = 150MB #This allows you to set the size beforehand
[Int16]$AmountOfFiles = 10
```

Self-explanatory but basically we can set the size and the amount of files we need.
The size can be anything, 1GB, 12MB, 15KB. Powershell will take care of the conversion.

```
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $AmountOfFiles; $i++)
```

An standard for loop:

1. It initiates a variable called `i` on 0 (that can also be used inside the `{ }` of the loop).
2. It sets the maximum amount of files allowed to be less than (`-lt`) the `$AmountOfFiles` variable, so in this case `$i` will reach 9 and then stop looping.
3. After each iteration, it will increase the value of `$i` by one

Finally:

```
$f = new-object System.IO.FileStream ".\test_$i.dat", Create, ReadWrite
$f.SetLength($Size)
$f.Close()
```

- The first line sets the new object that will create the "dummy" files, and will place them on the current directory and set the name to "test_#.dat" where # is the current iteration, the first one will be 0 and the last one will be 9 (test_0.dat .. test_9.dat).
- The second line sets the "length" of the file, that means it's size, in this case it's 150MB or 157286400 bytes.
- The last one simply stops the [FileStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream?view=net-6.0) and creates the file.